# Unity Setting Animator Parameters

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I'm trying to animate my player in Unity using the animator component but for some reason it seems that my character is stuck in the idle animation and I can't change the animation parameters from my code. I'm using a 2D freeform direction blend tree in unity, and I'm not exactly sure why it's not working. The animations themselves seem to be working fine when I change the parameters using the inspector.

`

```
void Update()
    {
    groundedPlayer = characterController.isGrounded;

    if (groundedPlayer && playerVelocity.y < 0)
    {
        playerVelocity.y = 0f;
    }

    Vector2 input = moveAction.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    Vector3 move = new Vector3(input.x, 0, input.y);

    move = move.x * cameraTransform.right.normalized + move.z * cameraTransform.forward.normalized;
    move.y = 0f;

    animator.SetFloat(moveXAnimationParameterId, input.x);
    animator.SetFloat(moveZAnimationParameterId, input.y);

    characterController.Move(move * Time.deltaTime * playerSpeed);

    if (jumpAction.triggered && groundedPlayer)
    {
        playerVelocity.y += Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -3.0f * gravityValue);

        if (move != Vector3.zero)
        {
            animator.Play(runningJumpAnimation);

        }
        else
        {
            animator.Play(jumpAnimation);
        }
    }

    playerVelocity.y += gravityValue * Time.deltaTime;
    characterController.Move(playerVelocity * Time.deltaTime);

    float targetAngle = cameraTransform.eulerAngles.y;
    Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, targetAngle, 0);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);



 }
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using animator.Play I suggest you use conditions using for example :

```
_anim.SetBool("isRunning",true);
```

[image]